# The set $A := \{ (x,y) : y \in f(x,x+1) \}$ is closed if $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let  $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$  continuous.
>
> I need to prove that **$A := \{ (x,y) : y \in f(x,x+1) \}$** is closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

We have that $\mathbb{A}$ is the union of all the Cartesian products **${x}\times f(x,x+1)$** for each $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

With results from compact sets I've proven that each **${x}\times f(x,x+1)$** is closed.

To prove that $\mathbb{A}$ is closed it would be useful that the following lemma would also be true:

Let **$\mathbb{X}$** be a topological space and **$\{\mathbb{A}(i)\}$** a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{X}$ indexed in a set **$\mathbb{I}$**. If $z$ is adherent to **$\mathbb{U}\{A(i) : i \in \mathbb{I}\}$**, the union of the sets $\mathbb{A}(i)$, then there exists some $k$ in $\mathbb{I}$ such that $z$ is adherent to $\mathbb{A}(k)$.

So is this lemma (conjecture so far) true?

Comment: Use TeX commands while editing math symbols

Comment: Have you drawn a picture of what A might look like for a typical f?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x_n \to x, y_n \to y$ with $(x_n ,y_n) \in A$, then there is some $\xi_n \in [x_n,x_n+1]$ such that $y_n = f(\xi_n)$.

Hence $\xi_n $ lies in some bounded set and so $\xi_{n_k} \to \xi$ for some $\xi$ and some subsequence $n_k$. Since $x_n \le \xi_n \le x_n+1$ for all $n$ we have $x\le \xi \le x+1$, and by continuity, we have $y=f(\xi)$.

Hence $(x,y) \in A$ and so $A$ is closed.